# Functions return error 'NameError: name 'context_word' is not defined' when using global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, search, tkinter

I've got some code that creates a context menu when the user selected a word in a tkinter text widget. The text widget automatically checks to see if the word is correct every time 'space' is pressed. if the selected word is incorrect, part of the context menu asks the user if they would like to correct the word. This should then get the selected word, loop through the text widget (using the search method) until it's found an instance of the word, then replace it with the correct word.

Here is my code (don't mind the 'WOOOO!', it just allows the user to use the context menu with out selecting a word)

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

notepad = Text(root)

def replace_word():
    global selected_word
    global context_word

    replace_start = notepad.search(selected_word, 1.0, END)

    while replace_start:
        replace_offset = '+%dc' % len(selected_word)

        replace_end = replace_start + replace_offset

        notepad.delete(replace_start, replace_end)

        notepad.insert(replace_start, context_word)

        replace_start = notepad.search(replace_start, 1.0, END)


def add_to_dictionary_context():
    global selected_word
    global context_word
    global spell_dict

    spell_dict.word_frequency.add(selected_word)

    with open('dictionary_file_add.txt', 'a+') as f_context:
        selected_word_to_add = selected_word + '\n'
        f_context.write(selected_word_to_add)




def notepad_context_menu(event):
    global spell_dict

    context_menu = Menu(notepad_frame, tearoff = 0)

    try:
        selected_word = notepad.selection_get().strip('\n')
        context_word = spell_dict.correction(selected_word)

        if (selected_word not in spell_dict) and (selected_word != context_word): # Makes sure selected_word is incorrect

            dictionary_context = Menu(context_menu, tearoff = 0)
            context_menu.add_cascade(label = "Dictionary... ", menu = dictionary_context)

            dictionary_context.add_command(label = context_word, command = replace_word)
            dictionary_context.add_command(label = "Add to dictionary", command = add_to_dictionary_context)
            context_menu.add_separator()

    except:
        print("WOOOO!")

    context_menu.add_command(label = "Undo", command = undo)
    context_menu.add_command(label = "Redo", command = redo)

    context_menu.add_separator()

    context_menu.add_command(label = "Cut", command = cut)
    context_menu.add_command(label = "Copy", command = copy)
    context_menu.add_command(label = "Paste", command = paste)


    try:
        context_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        context_menu.grab_release()
notepad.bind('<Button-3>', notepad_context_menu)
root.mainloop()
```

However, when I run this code, if I press the replace word button in the context menu it returns the error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python stuff\Other apps\Veteris\Scripts\Veteris_program.py", line 1058, in replace_word
    replace_start = notepad.search(selected_word, 1.0, END)
NameError: name 'selected_word' is not defined
```

and if I press the 'Add to dictionary' button it returns:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python stuff\Other apps\Veteris\Scripts\Veteris_program.py", line 1068, in replace_word
    notepad.insert(replace_start, context_word)
NameError: name 'context_word' is not defined
```

Basically, my code isn't reading my global statements. My add_word_to_dictionary_context() and replace_word() functions only run after I've declared context_word and selected_word.

I've tried putting

```
selected_word = ''
context_word = ''
```

at the start, and no error is returned but nothing happens. I've also tried putting replace_word() and add_to_dictionary-context() after notepad_context_menu(), but it still spits the same errors.
I'm really stuck.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The code you provided is not testable. You are having an issue with global but all you show us is a function that uses global. Please reduce your code to 1 testable example of the problem.

Comment: @Mike If I was to provide testable code I would have to provide 500+ lines of code, and because I am new to python and I don't understand what is wrong with my code, I cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: I did tell you why. Your code is not testable. We don't need to see your full function. We need to be able to copy paste and run to see where the error occurs. Please read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Incorrect. You can always reduce code down to a small section that can reproduce the problem. In doing so you may even find out what the problem was on your own. That is one of the benefits of generating a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: @Mike-SMT While I agree a reprex would be nice, and good exercise, this question is answerable with the code given by looking at the `global` declarations.

Comment: @Mike-SMT anyway I have edited the code. It should be reproducible now :)

Comment: Well really you just added a mainloop. Nothing calls your functions. In any case AKX answer your question. Please in the future try to create a MRE for your post.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Sorry, I forgot to add bind(). Should be working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the `global` statements to the functions where you *assign* (write, as it were) into the global functions, not into those which just read them.

Your code is writing them in the `notepad_context_menu` function:

```
selected_word = notepad.selection_get().strip('\n')
context_word = spell_dict.correction(selected_word)
```

and since you don't have declared them `global` in that function, they're just local variables which get "thrown away".

On the other hand, you don't need to declare `spell_dict` global in any of these functions, since you're not assigning into it.

That said, it'd be much better not to use global variables to begin with, e.g. by using [anonymous `lambda` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful) that capture those values and pass them in:

```py
def replace_word(selected_word, context_word):
    pass  # ...


def add_to_dictionary_context(selected_word):
    spell_dict.word_frequency.add(selected_word)
    # ...

def notepad_context_menu(event):
    # ...
    selected_word = notepad.selection_get().strip("\n")
    context_word = spell_dict.correction(selected_word)
    # ...
    dictionary_context.add_command(
        label=context_word,
        command=lambda: replace_word(selected_word, context_word),
    )
    dictionary_context.add_command(
        label="Add to dictionary",
        command=lambda: add_to_dictionary_context(selected_word),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of using lambda - to be honest I haven't ever used lambda, I find them scary. I just need to practice using them though

Comment: @jack.py what about a lambda do you find scary? I know at first they can be confusing but they are simply a function without a name. Personally I like to build tkinter using class inherency that way I can use class methods and attributes instead of globals.

Comment: @Mike-SMT No one ever really taught them to me, so I don't know exactly how they work. I have just never used them in a practical way, so I don't know how to implement them to make them useful

Comment: @jack.py. Ok. Well keep in mind they are basically a one liner function. They are quite useful for many things.

Comment: @AKX Thanks a heap dude. Just tested my code properly, and it works like a charm. Really, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this was answer already by AKX but as explained you should be posting a MRE. Though you have updated your question it is still not an MRE. You are missing the required import for spell checking and your notepad was never added to the screen.

Here is an example of what an MRE might look like including correction to make it work.

You needed to provide global for `context_word` and `selected_word` into your `notepad_context_menu`. They way functions look for variable is like this:

First it checks locally for the variable and if the variable is not defined locally it will then check the global namespace for the variable. So for functions that only work with the variable and do not define it we do not need the global defined in the function. However for functions that will be defining a variable IE `var = something` then we need to set the global in the function.

I also added global to your `replace_word` function as here I am resetting `context_word` and `selected_word` back to `""` after replace is finished.

Note I removed all the parts that are not part of the testing for this issue. IE all the context_menu items unrelated to the spell check and the redundant `replace_start` in your function.

Lastly I made some PEP8 changes to your formatting.

Let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk
import spellchecker as sc


root = tk.Tk()

notepad = tk.Text(root)
notepad.pack()
spell_dict = sc.SpellChecker()
context_word = ''
selected_word = ''


def replace_word():
    global context_word, context_word, selected_word

    replace_start = notepad.search(selected_word, 1.0, "end")
    replace_offset = '+%dc' % len(selected_word)
    replace_end = replace_start + replace_offset
    notepad.delete(replace_start, replace_end)
    notepad.insert(replace_start, context_word)
    context_word = ''  # added to reset context and selected words.
    selected_word = ''


def add_to_dictionary_context():
    global selected_word
    spell_dict.word_frequency.add(selected_word)

    with open('dictionary_file_add.txt', 'a+') as f_context:
        selected_word_to_add = selected_word + '\n'
        f_context.write(selected_word_to_add)


def notepad_context_menu(event):
    global spell_dict, selected_word, context_word
    context_menu = tk.Menu(notepad, tearoff=0)

    try:
        selected_word = notepad.selection_get().strip('\n')
        context_word = spell_dict.correction(selected_word)
        if selected_word not in spell_dict and selected_word != context_word:
            dictionary_context = tk.Menu(context_menu, tearoff=0)
            context_menu.add_cascade(label="Dictionary... ", menu=dictionary_context)
            dictionary_context.add_command(label=context_word, command=replace_word)
            dictionary_context.add_command(label="Add to dictionary", command=add_to_dictionary_context)
            context_menu.add_separator()
    except:
        print("WOOOO!")

    try:
        context_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        context_menu.grab_release()


notepad.bind('<Button-3>', notepad_context_menu)
root.mainloop()
```